# How to monitor the use of memory in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, memory

My android app after launching starts to eat the phone's memory (not operational) After a few minutes, all of the phone's memory (more than 20gb) available.

How to trace where it goes? I try to search this question, but found only monitor operational memory

Answer (score 0):

Android Monitor window in Android Studio IDE helps you. Find Memory tab inside the Android Monitor window and start tracking your memory allocations. 
This link might be helpful. http://developer.android.com/tools/help/android-monitor.html

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the Allocation Tracker tool along with [other memory tools](http://developer.android.com/tools/performance/comparison.html) in Android Studio.  According to the [developer docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/performance/allocation-tracker/index.html):

> Allocation Tracker records each memory allocation that your app
>   performs during the profiling cycle. You tell Allocation Tracker to
>   start recording and it logs allocations until you tell it to stop.

You will have to choose to record allocations for a certain period of time to see what was allocated during that time.  There isn't really a way to leave it running indefinitely and have it report over long periods of time.